# ruby hash with methods on pair

Tags: ruby, hash

I'm using a rake task to receive and handle data.

The data looks like `"code:value"` where each code maps to a specific action.

For example, `"0xFE:0x47"` calls the method corresponding to the `0xFE` tag with the parameter `0x47`.

For scalability purposes I think this should be mapped to an hash and have the methods defined below:

```
tags = Hash[0xFA => taskA, 0xFB => taskB, 0xFC => taskC]

def taskA(value)
  ...
end

def taskB(value)
  ...
end

def taskC(value)
  ...
end
```

then, when a message is received, do a `split` and call the method on the hash, like:

```
tokens = message.split(':')
tags[tokens[0]](tokens[1])
```

Ruby doesn't like the `Hash` initialization. What's the correct way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you're expecting the methods to work like they do in JavaScript, where they're just references until called, but this is not the case. The best approach is to keep them as symbols and then use the `send` method to call them:

```
# Define a mapping table between token and method to call
tags = {
  0xFA => :taskA,
  0xFB => :taskB,
  0xFC => :taskC
}

tokens = message.split(/:/)

# Call the method and pass through the value
send(tags[tokens[0]], tokens[1])
```

The `Hash[]` initializer is usually reserved for special cases, such as when converting an Array into a Hash. In this case it's redundant if not confusing so is best omitted. `{ ... }` has the effect of creating a Hash implicitly.

Comment: I already used a similar implementation in JavaScript :) either way, send method worked great.

Comment: In JavaScript, `taskA` is a method reference and `taskA()` is a method call. In Ruby, `taskA` and `taskA()` are both method calls since the brackets are optional. You can capture a Proc using `taskA_proc = method(:taskA)` and then call it later with `taskA_proc.call()` but this is usually more awkward than just using `send`.

Answer (score 2):

Define "doesn't like".

If you try to initialize the hash using function names:

1. Before the function is defined, you'll get an undefined symbol.
2. After the function is defined, you're just executing the function.

If you want to map values to functions you can call, consider defining the methods as Procs/lambdas:

```
> taskA = lambda { |value| puts "foo #{value}" }
> h = { 0x42 => taskA }
> h[0x42].call("bar")
foo bar
```

You could store symbols, too, but I prefer to use known-existing artifacts, like a variable, so an IDE can help me make sure I'm doing things as right as it can know–symbols are arbitrary and there's no way to make sure they align with an existing method other than trying to call it.

Comment: This works just fine and thanks for the heads up on how ruby works with functions. But I end up going @tadman solution beucase it seems more clean. either way +1 for a working answer

Comment: @Daniel IMO it's actually less clean because of the increased chance of errors, but unit testing can help eliminate that. IMO the methods should really be classes with a known interface; *that's* the cleanest--IDE assistance, encapsulation, and no need to throw symbols around.